# Configure nginx caching with header cache_key

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

How can I configure nginx to cache the body of a response, with the cache_key being a header in the response. for example:

POST domain/user
returns body {"id": 1, "name":"user-1"} with header Location: /user/1

GET domain/user/1 returns cached body of previous POST

I tried nginx cache configuration default, but a i not can define the header as a cache_key and cache the response of post